# error Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) when inserting data from a text file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

got about 20 to 50 rows in a text file  to insert into my database 'bourse' using sql server management studio 2012 my database 'bourse contains certain number of tables for example i have the table **IB_emetteur** it has 3 attributes (c_emetteur , libelle , mnemes ) 
and i have the data in a text file structured like this :

```
1,UFI,U.F.I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
2,TSI, T.S.I                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
3,ADAY,A.Day                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
5,CAPITAL,C.PITAL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
7,COFCAP,COFjuil                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
8,SFI,SUIhyuo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
9,AFC,A.KIYUI                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
13,CGI,chakoqguio                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
14,BNAC,banque hyuijsii
```

i have to insert this data in my table so i used this query :

```
bulk insert [dbo].[IB_Emetteur]
from 'C:\Users\Manu\Documents\GL5\Finance\liste_emetteur.txt'
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')
go
```

but i got this error 
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 2 (mnemes)

Comment: This error is just telling you that BULK INSERT is seeing the data as too large for the Column `mnemes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
`bulk insert [dbo].[IB_Emetteur]
from 'C:\Users\Manu\Documents\GL5\Finance\liste_emetteur.txt'
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n',FIRSTROW = 2)
go`